# Error upon inserting excel formula from Python to excel tab

Tags: python, excel

So I was asked to insert this formula to each tab in excel. Problem is caused by "=" because if I remove "=" from below code it works just fine.

I use library openpyxl

```
page['%s%s' % (slownik['transport cost per m3'], str(k))] = "=JEŻELI.BĄŁD(" + slownik['price per truck'] + str(k) + "/" + \
                                                            slownik['m3 per truck'] + ")" + str(k)
```

I got an error and excel breaks.

This below works just fine.

```
page['%s%s' % (slownik['transport cost per m3'], str(k))] = "JEŻELI.BĄŁD(" + slownik['price per truck'] + str(k) + "/" + \
                                                                slownik['m3 per truck'] + ")" + str(k)
```

Comment: What type of error, and what do you mean by "breaks"? Have you tried with a simple formula, such as =1+1? Maybe the problem is the formula, and that error is just excel barking back?

Comment: Tried, simple formula with plus works. Formula is correct. Checked manually. By break I mean that I get information it's damaged and try to restore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so. First of all formula should be done in english. Also In formula I shouldn't use
***";"***
I should use:"***,***"
So in the end formula inside python looks like this:

```
page['%s%s' % (slownik['transport cost per m3'], str(k))] = "=IFERROR(" + slownik['price per truck'] + str(k) + "/" + slownik['m3 per truck'] + str(k) + ",0)"
```